# undefined method `change'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm  doing the ruby on rails tutorial, I specifically adding listing 8.21 to spec/requests/users_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do
  describe "signup" do
    describe "signup failure" do
      lambda do
        it "should not make a new user" do
          visit signup_path
          fill_in "Name",                       :with => ""
          fill_in "Email",                      :with => ""
          fill_in "Password",                   :with => ""
          fill_in "Password confirmation",      :with => ""
          click_button
          response.should render_template('users/new')
          response.should have_selector("div#error_explanation")
        end
      end.should_not change(User, :count)
    end
  end
end
```

as far as I can tell, this is exactly like the listing in 8.21; however, when I run

```
rspec spec/requests/users_spec.rb -e "Users"
```

I got the following error ...

```
#> rspec spec/requests/users_spec.rb -e "Users" No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ... /Users/bryanjamieson/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/users_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in ': undefined method `change' for
# (NoMethodError)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use User.count

```
end.should_not change(User.count)
```

Depending on which rails version and rspec version you're using (assuming Rails 3.1, Rspec2) the tutorial may be a little of out date

Comment: made no difference  I got the same error.  I used the same syntax in the spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb and spec does not complain when I run that.

Comment: I found the problem had the lambda block in the wrong place :)